# How can I pass an Extra to an Android intent using MonkeyRunner?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I am trying to test my app using the [MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) tool.  I am trying to add an EXTRA to my activity.  The python script executes without error:

```
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
device.wake()
extra = {'MY_EXTRA', True}
device.startActivity(component="org.mycompany.myapp/.activity.Show",extras=extra)
```

But when I inspect the intent in my app I do not get the value passed:

```
boolean myExtra = i.getBooleanExtra("MY_EXTRA", false);
```

What am I missing?  Am I passing in the intent wrong?  Am I inspecting the value in the Android app wrong?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in `MonkeyRunner`.  It is not correctly handling passing `boolean` into extras.  If you pass a string instead, it should work.

[This](https://review.source.android.com/#change,21636) fixes this issue.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to take any extra, string, boolean, nothing...hmm