# Posting an Intent from Python scripts using Monkey/Monkey Runner

Tags: android, python, android-intent, monkeyrunner

I am trying to test my apps using python and monkey runner.
I want to send an intent during start activity.
I tried using extras and this doesnt help.

Can some one help me with this? If possible can some one provide me a sample AndroidManifest.xml and test.py on how to do this.

Thank you all for the help
blr p sh

Comment: Why don't you post what you tried and what didn't work ?

Comment: @dtmilano....my Jython script is as follows:

Comment: extra = dict([('android.intent.action.MAIN', True)]) 

activity = 'com.abc.mynewapp.ui.MainScreen'

#sets the name of the component to start

runComponent = package + '/'+activity

#Runs the component
device.startActivity(component=runComponent, extras=extra)

Comment: The extras passed to startActivity is not doing the command on the ui.Mainscreen I want it do? How do I do that or alternatively post this intent. Thx a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs in monkeyrunner avoiding correct handling of extras. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891276/how-can-i-pass-an-extra-to-an-android-intent-using-monkeyrunner) also mentions the case passing booleans, but it's not restricted to them.

The workaround, as monkeyrunner does not do much that invoking ADB in this cases is to use

```
device.shell('am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n my.pkg/.MyActivity -e key val')
```